# Unable to Access the Virtual Machine VM via SSH outside of host machine network

Tags: networking, server, ssh, virtualbox, kvm-virtualization

Hi guys I have dedicated server running ubuntu 18.04 I installed KVM & CENTOS 8 VM on the system and I did bridge network settings on my VM and my host machine but when I am trying to access that guest virtual machine via SSH outside of my host network like from my home network it doesn't work says timeout `ssh root@192.168.30.96` this is the IP address of my virtual machine `192.168.30.96` & this is the ip address of my server `185.XXX.XX.XX` I am successfully able to login to my VM via SSH inside of host machine network my ubuntu server. But unable to login to VM via SSH outside of the host network like any network, home, office etc. How to resolve this issue any suggestions? Do I need to configure my network IP's or something? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Some internet providers block some known ports by default. Check it with your service provider!!

Comment: 192.168.30.96 is a private network only present on your Host. The same network will be present in many places, and not being public it isn't routed from e.g. your home to that. If you want to expose your guest to the public network you'll need to set it up that way on your Host. Check this for a start https://netplan.io/examples/#configuring-network-bridges

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for helping me out actually I figured it out I need to assign a static IP to my KVM VM and create the proper bridge from host to Guest VM once its assigned than I enabled the SSH access on my VM and open the SSH port now I can successfully access my VM from public networks even via SSH as well.